# Spring-boot bean name conflict between two dependent retrofit clients

Tags: spring-boot, maven

My maven springboot app has a dependency on two Retrofit clients whose code I have no control over. Both of these clients have a `@Configuration` class called ClientConfig. When I try to run my application, I get this error:

```
ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'clientConfig' for bean class [a.b.c.client.config.ClientConfig] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [a.b.c.config.ClientConfig]
```

How can I fix this? Is there any way I can override the bean names for these classes? This is my maven configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>a.b</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib1-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>a.b</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib2-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.55</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I could think of is to exclude them from component scan:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {"a.b.lib1-client",...})
```